# style linear-gradient is not supported by Trigger.io

Tags: css, trigger.io, linear-gradients

Hi i make a HTML5 application  running with Trigger.io and when i use the style

```
background:linear-gradient(#293d4f,#0d4f6e ) ;
```

in the catalyst (remote debugging tool ) it didn't figure,exactly the debugger didn't know it,
it replaced with

```
background:initial; (warning)
```

Comment: CSS features can depend on the device/OS, what did this occur on?

Comment: when I apply this style it work with the browser, but when I run it with Trigger.io is not showing the correct color, it display the white color . yes it have any relation with CSS. So the problem lies with Trigger.io

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Android WebView supports linear gradients but requires a -webkit prefix for most versions, so just change it to:

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#293d4f, #0d4f6e) ;
```

The same WebView component is used for Trigger apps that is used for the stock android browser. On Android 4.4, the WebView has been updated so you don't need the -webkit prefix.

See http://caniuse.com/css-gradients for more details (generally a great site for checking this sort of thing)

Comment: Hi, i try it but some problem here's the form style
http://www.imageurlhost.com/images/qzxsoo8pd9l3no1oj0_screen.png
i don't understand what is that warning !
i use the android emulator 2.2